# looping through value list for multiple url requests in python

Tags: python, pandas, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Weather Underground for years' worth of hourly data from multiple weather stations and put it into a pandas dataframe. I CANNOT use the API as there are limits on requests and I don't want to pay thousands of dollars to scrape this data.

I can get the script to scrape all of the data I want from one station. When I try to modify it so it loops through a list of stations I either get a 406 error or it returns only the data from the first station in my list. How can I loop through all the stations? Also how can I store the station name so that it can be added to the dataframe in another column?

here is what my code looks like now:

```
 stations = ['EGMC','KSAT','CAHR']


weather_data = []
date = []
for s in stations:
    for y in range(2014,2015):
        for m in range(1, 13):
            for d in range(1, 32):
            #check if a leap year
                if y%400 == 0:
                    leap = True
                elif y%100 == 0:
                    leap = False
                elif y%4 == 0:
                    leap = True
                else:
                    leap = False

            #check to see if dates have already been scraped    

            if (m==2 and leap and d>29):
                continue
            elif (y==2013 and m==2 and d > 28):
                continue
            elif(m in [4, 6, 9, 11] and d > 30):
                continue

            timestamp = str(y) + str(m) + str(d)
            print ('Getting data for ' + timestamp)

#pull URL
            url = 'http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/{0}/' + str(y) + '/' + str(m) + '/' + str(d) + '/DailyHistory.html?HideSpecis=1'.format(stations)
            page = urlopen(url)

        #find the correct piece of data on the page
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')



            for row in soup.select("table tr.no-metars"):
                date.append(str(y) + '/' + str(m) + '/' + str(d))
                cells = [cell.text.strip().encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii') for cell in row.find_all('td')]
                weather_data.append(cells)

weather_datadf = pd.DataFrame(weather_data)
datedf = pd.DataFrame(date)
result = pd.concat([datedf, weather_datadf], axis=1)
result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is explanation of your error https://httpstatuses.com/406

You should add `User-Agent` to headers. But I think on this site exist some protection from crawling and you should use more specific things like Scrapy, Crawlera, proxy-list, user-agent rotator